# C++ objcopy to make class method weak

Tags: c++, g++, clang

I have this header file:

#### weather.h

```
#ifndef _WEATHER_H_
#define _WEATHER_H_

#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Weather {
    private:
        int temp;
    
    public:
        Weather();
        string announce();
};

#endif
```

When I compile the related source file, I want to make announce and Weather (the default constructor) weak during compile time.

To do so, the flow looks something like:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -g -Wall -c weather.cpp
objcopy --weaken-symbol=announce --weaken-symbol=Weather weather.o weather.o
```

However, when I then compile another version of weather without the weakening? I still get a duplicate symbol error.

I know --weaken exists, but this is just a sample and I do not want to blanket weaken every method in the class.

Comment: Can you post the relevant `readelf` lines from both weather.o files to confirm one is weak and the other is not? Does using `--weaken-symbol announce` without the equals sign make any difference?

Comment: Your C++ compiler, like every other C++ compiler in existence, uses name mangling. You need to figure out the mangled names of the constructor and announce. I can guarantee you, with 100% certainty, that it's not "Weather" and "announce".

Comment: @Paul Objdump isn't showing any weak symbols, and I'm seeing different behavior than when I manually insert weak attributes in the header file (which I don't want to do)

SamVarshavchik even when I specify the mangled symbol name it does not work

Comment: @jajabarr Seems to work fine for me. I'll add my solution in an answer

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_WEATHER_H_`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don’t use them in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weakening the symbols in the one file and linking all the objects together works for me. Make sure you are relinking all the objects (including all constructors).

**weather1.cpp**

```
Weather::Weather() {}
string Weather::announce()
{
    return string("Bad weather");
}
```

**weather2.cpp**

```
Weather::Weather() {}
string Weather::announce()
{
    return string("Bad weather 2");
}
```

**build.sh**

```
g++ weather1.cpp -c -o weather1.o
g++ weather2.cpp -c -o weather2.o
g++ test.cpp -c -o test.o

objcopy --weaken-symbol=_ZN7Weather8announceEv --weaken-symbol=_ZN7WeatherC2Ev --weaken-symbol=_ZN7WeatherC1Ev weather2.o weather2.o

g++ *.o -o test.out
```

Depending on whether I weaken weather1.o or weather2.o, I see different outputs from my test main function:

```
int main()
{
    Weather w;
    std::cout << w.announce() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Similarly, it also works to weaken only certain symbols and redefine those in the other file.

Comment: Interesting to note that if both functions are marked weak, the first one in the final link command will be the one used.

Comment: This is what I ended up finding - Thank you! Funnily enough I had the code for this written but it wasn't working on mac. I found a bug thread saying objcopy had some issues with macOS and x86 architecture - I ended up having to run it in a linux VM to see any progress.